# iTunes connect description localization in Bulgarian

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My iOS app is localized in Bulgarian and I want to add a description in Bulgarian in iTunes connect. The language is not listed in the drop down menu. Is it possible to add it?

Comment: According to [App Store Territories and Localizations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html), Bulgaria as a country is supported for application to be sold there, but Bulgarian language is not among the few languages supported for displaying metadata. Either contact Apple to influence them to add your language, or just set English as your primary language for localization so that Bulgarian users will see description in English as a fallback.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! You are correct!